# Cypress: Getting 'TypeError', while returning values from a Page object class function

Tags: javascript, typeerror, cypress

Not able to return values from a Page object class function, where as same function is returns values through custom command.

**Custom command function: [This will return 10 texts]**

```
Cypress.Commands.add("defultPrelist", () => {
    cy.get('div[class="css-tpolag"]').then(function($elem) {                     
        const presetList_Name = $elem.text()  
        return cy.wrap(presetList_Name)
       })
    })
```

**Main cypress driver class (where i need the custom function returned values)**

```
describe('Defult PresetsList Validation', function() {
   it('Defult PresetList', function() {
   cy.defultPrelist().then(presetList_Name => {
   cy.log(presetList_Name);    
    }) })
```

and here i could use the values of custom command function.
Now the problem is if i use the same custom command function in a page object class and try to returned in main cypress class getting 'TypeError'.

**Page Object Class function: (Same as above custom command function)**

```
class ManagePresetPopup {
   defultPreset () {
   cy.get('div[class="css-tpolag"]').then(function($elem) {                     
   const presetList_Name = $elem.text()  
   return cy.wrap(presetList_Name)
 })
 }}
export default ManagePresetPopup
```

**Main cypress driver class (where i need the page object class function returned values)**

```
describe('Defult PresetsList Validation', function() {
   it('Defult PresetList', function() {    
    const defultPrelist = new ManagePresetPopup()    
     defultPrelist.defultPreset().then(presetList_Name => {
     cy.log(presetList_Name);
  }) 
 }) }}
```

But here i am getting error as 'TypeError Cannot read property 'then' of undefined' in following line : **'defultPrelist.defultPreset().then(presetList_Name =>'**